# How to combine Dash and Flask login without using iframe?

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-login

I have a flask application, some pages of the app is protected with Flask-Login, I need to add Dash plot to my application, the plot should be on the page which requires authentification. I should add that in addition to Flask Login, I created user access levels using flask session.

I found how to combine Dash with protected page using iframe block, but I would like to try to make dash plot as a separate page (not iframe) with user authentification. If forget about authentification I have no problen to add Dash plot as a separate page in Flask app.

Typically I do the following to check login:

```
@app.route("/somempage", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@flask_login.login_required
def return_somepage():
    active_username = session['user_id']
    try:
        HOST, USER, PASSWORD, AUTH_PLUGIN = 
        InitSetup.read_mysql_init_config_file(WORKDIR +
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "mosreg_webscrap_website.config.txt"))
        conn, curs = MySQLOP.create_mysql_connection(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, 
        AUTH_PLUGIN)
        active_user = MySQLOP.retrieve_userinfo_from_db(curs, 
        active_username)
#now we check value of db colum and decide if user can see the page:
if active_user[0][4]:
    #show page
else:
    # return user have no rights to see the page template
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully added `@login_required` in my dash app, using the following:

#### in __init__.py of flask app

```py
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

# other stuff ...

@app.route("/dash", methods=['POST','GET'])
@login_required
def dash():
    return appdash.index()
```

### in dashapp.py

```py
appdash = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, server=app)
```

Notice that I did not define a route in the Dash app declaration (i.e. `routes_pathname_prefix='/dash'`), so Dash App may only be viewed through the route of my Flask app, to which I put `@login_required`.

`@login_required` in my case is the  one from [Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/)

Comment: Hi, although it's clear that you login_required 1 route, under which you can find the Dash app, I would love some clarification on the .index(), since a Dash app has an app, server and layouts?

Comment: @MauricioMaroto Hi, the key is  `appdash = ........., server=app)`, I set the server of dash `app` to be the one from Flask.

Answer (score 1):

I have manged to do that by using @login_required coupled with an in function condition to check if the user is logged in and authorized.
If not it will redirect him to the login page.

```
@main_bp.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return protected_view()
```

Adding more details..

```
## app.py
import flask_login
from flask_login import login_required
from flask_login import LoginManager

login_manager = LoginManager()

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
login_manager.init_app(app)

with app.app_context():
    # Import parts of our application
    from visual import routes, auth

    # Register Blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(routes.main_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(auth.auth_bp)

    # Create Database Models
    db.create_all()


## routes.py
from flask_login import current_user
from flask import current_app as app
from .assets import compile_auth_assets
from flask_login import login_required

# Blueprint Configuration
main_bp = Blueprint('main_bp', __name__,
                    template_folder='templates',
                    static_folder='static')
compile_auth_assets(app)


@main_bp.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return protected_view()
```

This tutorial should be useful..
https://scotch.io/tutorials/authentication-and-authorization-with-flask-login

Comment: Could you give more details, I tried to do the following but It didn't work: @app.route("/testme", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@flask_login.login_required
def dashboard():
    dash1 = dash.Dash(__name__)
    dash1.layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.H1("Hello")
    ])
    dash1.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', port=80000, debug=False)
    return dash1.index()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5003, debug=True)  # flask app

Comment: I'm trying to read your code, use formatting.
it seems that you aren't creating a flask application to begin with..
next, you can not return app.run 
What you should do is return dash.index()